# How to save only numbers from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

I want to extract only the numbers from a Python `list` where the input elements are `str`:

```
input_in_terminal = "5 43 8 109 32"

input_list = [5, ' ', 43, ' ', 8, ' ', 109, ' ', 32]
```

How can I extract only the numbers and create a list as below?

```
extracted_list = [5,43,8,109,32]
```

Comment: `[i for i in input_list if i != ' ']`

Comment: How did you get `input_list` from the input typed into the terminal? It sounds like you're doing a bunch of work you don't need, just to keep the parts of the input you don't want.

Comment: But better to just use `list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: `[int(word) for word in line.split()]` is all you need to handle your input line. `[elem for elem in lst if isinstance(elem, int)]` will filter the list you say you have—but as user suggests you probably shouldn’t have that list in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change input_list but list(map(int, input().split())) worked! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Python 3:

```
extracted_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != ' ' , input_list))
```

or if you want to avoid multiple spaces check if it's an integer and filter out anything that's not an integer.

```
extracted_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,int) , input_list))
```

If you need other kinds like float or complex you can do:

```
extracted_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x,(float,int,complex)) ,input_list))

speed: --- 6.818771362304688e-05 seconds ---
```

Or for any number

```
import numbers
input_list = [5, ' ', 43, ' ', 8, '   ', 109, ' ', 32, 3.14]
extracted_list = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number) ,input_list))

print (extracted_list)
```

---

you can test it here: http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_l6dgnVkb19Or9dN.py

Comment: This will filter out zeros, without filtering out whitespace.